# How to apply a shapekey to the Basis shapekey in Python?

Tags: python

I want to "apply" or "bake" a specific shapekey into the Basis (first) shapekey using Python.

Some shapekeys will remain which need to use this new Basis shapekey, so I assume they need to be recreated with the new Basis shapekey.

What I have so far:

```py
def bake_shapekeys(obj):
    print('Baking shapekeys for mesh "' + obj.name + '"...')
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.select_set(True)

    for key in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
        if key.name.endswith('_bake'):
            print('Found ' + key.name + '')
            
            # perform the bake

bake_shapekeys(my_mesh)
```

I am on Blender 3.3